# What happen when I increase the size of running volume of ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My question is so simple:
What happens when I increase the size of running volume of ec2 instance.

1) Does my all data wiped ?

2) Does the space of my instance will also modify with new size ?

Actually my instance has storage of 8GB and that is almost full. I want to increase space that can help me to save more files to my instance.

I have found this option in my console. 
I have found that connected ec2 volume. Does directly modifying the volume size will automatically reflect my instance space after reboot. 
I
know this is quiet simple. I am just worried about my existing data.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: If you are resizing the boot volume, Amazon Linux AMIs (most) will automatically detect the new volume size and resize the last file system in the partition table. Resizing an EC2 instance is safe, but I would create an AMI from the instance first. Then resize the instance. You can also just create a new instance from the AMI (that you created from the running instancve) with the desired volume size and then terminate the old instance after double checking everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can just modify the volume directly and this will not affect any file, it will take around 1 min or so to upgrade the size or you might want to restart your instance.
to ensure data safety you can create a snapshot of that volume and from that snapshot create a new volume of whatever size you want and delete the old volume which now contains old data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have found the option in console to modify the size of the instance and the Instance here is Linux Instance. What the other answer forgets to mentions an important thing that is according to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/console-modify.html):

> Modifying volume size has no practical effect until you also extend
>   the volume's file system to make use of the new storage capacity. For
>   more information, see Extending a Linux File System after Resizing the
>   Volume.

For ext2, ext3, and ext4 file systems, this command is **resize2fs**. For XFS file systems, this command is **xfs_growfs**

**Note**:

*If the volume you are extending has been partitioned, you need to increase the size of the partition before you can resize the file system*

**To check if your volume partition needs resizing:**

Use the lsblk command to list the block devices attached to your instance. The example below shows three volumes: /dev/xvda, /dev/xvdb, and /dev/xvdf.

In Case if the partition occupies all of the room on the device, so it does not need resizing.

However, `/dev/xvdf1`if is an 8-GiB partition on a 35-GiB device and there are no other partitions on the volume. In this case, the partition must be resized in order to use the remaining space on the volume.

**To extend a Linux file system**

- Log In to Instance via SSH
- Use the **df -h** command to report the existing disk space usage on the file system.
- Expand the modified partition using **growpart** (and note the unusual syntax of separating the device name from the partition number):

`sudo growpart /dev/xvdf 1`

- Then Use a file system-specific command to resize each file system to the new volume capacity.
- Finally Use the **df -h** command to report the existing file system disk space usage

***Note : It is Recommended to take snapshot of ebs volume before making any changes.***

Please Refer to this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of this if you can stop and start the instance... from memory, I think it's the `growroot` module of `dracut` should automatically repartition and grow the root filesystem when it next starts.  These are usually already on the machine.  (That's why if you start a machine from scratch with a larger-than-default root partition, it's all immediately usable).